# Using regular expressions to replace constants by functions

Tags: pattern-matching, regular-expressions

I have an expression of the form:

```
expression = A1*x + A2*x^2 + ...
```

and I would like to replace `A1` by `F1[y]`, `A2` by `F2[y]`, etc.

Regular expressions would seem to be the thing to use, but since the above is not a string, I'm not sure how to do this.  Would like the solution to be something simple like

```
expression /. A* :> F*[y]
```

but of course this doesn't work.

How do I accomplish the above?

Comment: How are you generating your `expression`? It might be easier to replace `A1`,`A2`,… by `A[1]`,`A[2]`,…. Then, replacement becomes as simple as `expression /. A[i_] :> F[i][y]`. As a general rule i try to keep any information that I might need again out of symbol names - most function have no issue with composite heads, and it makes extracting the information so much easier

Comment: Yeah that's the problem, the output is from a function in the xAct xTras package and it spits out expressions of the above form with Ai's, rather than A[i]'s. Doesn't seem to be a way of changing it. (MakeContractionAnsatz)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`SymbolName`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SymbolName) to convert symbols to their string names, and then process those strings:

```
ReplaceAll[
    A1*x + A2*x^2 + A3*x^3,
    s_Symbol :> Module[{n = SymbolName[s]},
        Symbol[StringReplace[n, "A"->"F"]][y] /; StringMatchQ[n, "A"~~DigitCharacter..]
    ]
]
```

> x F1[y] + x^2 F2[y] + x^3 F3[y]

Comment: Beautiful, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here is an approach based on string manipulation:

```
expression = A1 x + A2 x^2 + A3 x^3;

ToString@InputForm@expression;
StringReplace[%, "A" ~~ n : DigitCharacter :> "F" ~~ n ~~ "[y]"];
ToExpression@%

(* x F1[y] + x^2 F2[y] + x^3 F3[y] *)
```